Movie about a mechanic giving life lessons and optimism to a dejected sportsman
Possible year of release : No idea. Definitely after 1990 and before 2010. I rarely watch older movies and I don't think it's a recent movie. English movie, made in the U.S.
Genre, Characters, Plot : Drama. There is older character, probably 60-ish, in the movie. He is a kinda "realised soul", somewhat like a zen-master-like wisdom about life, probably a God come down to train humans ?. In his day-job in the movie, he is a mechanic, but I am not so sure about this part. I hazily remember this character could be Morgan Freeman, but it may not be him. I have looked through his movie list on wikipedia and none of them seem to ring a bell. 
One sure hint : The movies is replete with life lessons, punchlines of life wisdom, about optimism, motivation, about oneness etc. 
There is a younger character. This is probably a sportsman or bikeman or something, not sure about this part. He is probably dejected or generally dissatisfied with life or is not having success in his sport or looking for a big success and feeling inadequate for it. From time to time, in the movie, he meets the older character, pours out his problems and draws inspiration from the conversations. 
Probably there is a mechanic shop or a motorbike setting to their meetings and lessons. The older one has a god-like aura (not a physical one, but in the picturization of conversations). 
p.s. Please note that some words in the title could be misleading as I have mentioned in the details above what I am not clear about. 

Possibly Peaceful Warrior (2006) with Nick Nolte

A chance encounter with a stranger changes the life of a college gymnast.





Dan Millman is a university student as well as a locally famous gymnast who dreams of winning a National Championship competition. He suffers from restlessness, and on one occasion, Dan attempts to compensate for the restlessness by running along streets before sunrise. At a car-service station, he encounters an old man who seems to know more about Dan's problem than Dan himself knows, whom Dan later nicknames "Socrates". 
Socrates, prodded by the impatient and defiant Dan, gives the boy a series of tasks and lessons. The central concept of "Soc's" philosophy is this: that one must live entirely in the present moment. Other ideas include the related notion that at no time is "nothing going on" and the idea that an appropriate time exists for fighting and another for abstaining from violence. These lessons are conveyed through practical lessons, long contemplation, and one spectacular mystical experience. Dan gradually learns to appreciate every moment; to view the journey toward a goal as more meaningful and significant than the attainment; to pay attention to that which he is doing – thus increasing his gymnastic prowess; and (to a slightly lesser extent) control himself. Throughout the lesson, Dan learns virtually nothing about his mentor, other than the philosophy, Socrates' belief that service is the most noble action possible (hence his choice to work as a car serviceman), and the presence of another protégé.
...
Slightly before the competition, Dan diverts the bus he is riding to Socrates' station, only to find that Socrates has vanished without a trace.
Wikipedia


Wow, you guys are totally amazing, that's the one. You could find the right one, in spite of the messup in the details.
